# How to get a latest or max folder version?

Tags: c#, get, version, directory

I have some version folders like Vx_x_x

I want to retrieve the max folder version.

For example:

Folder contains,

```
 V8_2_1
 V9_3_2
 V10_4_1
```

I want to check the max number next to V and so on to get a latest folder version.

I am able to get a list of folders, But confusion to get how can I get a max number. If anyone can suggest me would me a great helpful. Thank you.

```
private static void GetFolderVersion()
{
     string startFolder = @"C:\Version\";
     System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(startFolder);
     IEnumerable<System.IO.DirectoryInfo> directoryList = dir.GetDirectories("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);           
}
```

Comment: Do you ever have a `itemA_v8` and `itemB_v8`?

Comment: Yes. I do have same version with different name folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider using the built-in `System.Version` type. Assuming all directory names are in the same format of "VX_Y_Z" (where X, Y and Z represent one or more digits, and V represents a literal "V"), the following code will do what you want:

```
public string GetMaxVersion(IEnumerable<string> directoryNames)
{
    var vDict = directoryNames.ToDictionary(
        s => new Version(s.Substring(1).Replace("_", ".")),
        s => s);
    var maxKey = vDict.Keys.Max();
    return vDict[maxKey];
}
```

Here we build a dictionary of version to file name mappings (note that we change the string format from "VX_Y_Z" to "X.Y.Z" to be able to create a `System.Version` object). All that remains is to retrieve the max value of all dictionary keys, and return the value assigned to that given key, which will be the directory name you're looking for.

**UPDATE:** For completeness, here's a piece of code that uses the method above and takes care of everything:

```
public string GetMaxVersionDirectory(string rootDirectory)
{
    var dirNames = Directory.GetDirectories(rootDirectory, "V*_*_*")
        .Select(dir => Path.GetFileName(dir));
    return GetMaxVersion(dirNames);
}
```

In your case, you need to pass `@"C:\Version"` as the `rootDirectory` parameter.

Comment: This is the best answer imo

Answer (score 0):

Although this probably does work, it's advisable to use the solution by @jbartuszek that uses the `Version` class.

Something along these lines could do it, but be aware that this is from the top of my head, written in notepad so might not build or contain some form of logical error. This just demonstrates the gist of it:

```
string[] version = folderName.Split('_');
string[] otherVersion = otherFolderName.Split('_');
```

then you write a method that checks the individual parts of the version:

```
private int CompareVersions(string[] version, string[] otherVersion)
{
    //we won't need the first character (the 'V')
    int vmajor = int.Parse(version[0].Substring(1));
    int vminor = int.Parse(version[1]);
    int vrevision = int.Parse(version[2]);

    int ovmajor = int.Parse(otherVersion[0].Substring(1));
    int ovminor = int.Parse(otherVersion[1]);
    int ovrevision = int.Parse(otherVersion[2]);

    int majorCompare = vmajor.CompareTo(ovmajor);

    //check if major already decides outcome
    if(majorCompare != 0)
    {
        return majorCompare;
    }

    int minorCompare = vminor.CompareTo(ovminor);

    //then if major equal, check if minor decides outcome
    if(minorCompare != 0)
    {
        return minorCompare;
    }

    //lastly, return outcome of revision compare
    return vrevision.CompareTo(ovrevision);
}
```

this is how you'd compare two folder names. If you wanted to get the max folder version, you could `foreach` the folder names:

```
//we'll start out by assigning the first folder name as a preliminary max
string maxFolder = folderNames[1];
string[] maxFolderVersion = maxFolder.Split('_');

foreach(string folderName in folderNames)
{
    if(CompareVersions(folderName.Split('_'), maxFolderVersion) > 0)
    {
        maxFolder = folderName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the files all match the pattern you gave, I'd be tempted to extract the version information using a regular expression, then selecting the highest value, starting with the major version and working out.

Update: replace the V in the regular expression with the correct prefix for your case.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^V(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var versions = directoryList 
    .Select(f => regex.Match(f))
    .Where(m => m.Success)
    .Select(m => new
    {
        Major = Int32.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value),
        Minor = Int32.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value),
        Patch = Int32.Parse(m.Groups[3].Value)
    }).ToList();

    var major = versions.Max(a => a.Major);
    versions = versions
        .Where(a => a.Major == major)
        .ToList();

    var minor = versions.Max(a => a.Minor);
    versions = versions
        .Where(a => a.Minor == minor)
        .ToList();

    var patch = versions.Max(a => a.Patch);
    versions = versions
        .Where(a => a.Patch == patch)
        .ToList();

    var newest = versions.First();

    var filename = String.Format("V_{0}_{1}_{2}", newest.Major, newest.Minor, newest.Patch);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mathematical approach. Let's say every single part of your version can go up to max. 1000. So the base is 1000. The version parts are your coefficents and the exponents are built in your loop. By summing up coefficent*base^exp you get a value which you can compare to get the highest version:

```
private static string GetHighestFolderVersion()
{

    string startFolder = @"C:\Version\";
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(startFolder);
    IEnumerable<System.IO.DirectoryInfo> directoryList = dir.GetDirectories("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    KeyValuePair<string, long> highestVersion = new KeyValuePair<string, long>("", 0);
    foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo in directoryList)
    {
        string versionOrigName = dirInfo.Name;
        string versionStr = versionOrigName.Substring(1);
        List<string> versionParts = versionStr.Split('_').ToList<string>();

        long versionVal = 0;
        int exp = 0;
        for (int i = versionParts.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
        {
            versionVal += (long.Parse(versionParts[i]) * (long)(Math.Pow(1000, exp)));
            exp++;
        }

        if (versionVal > highestVersion.Value)
        {
            highestVersion = new KeyValuePair<string, long>(versionOrigName, versionVal);
        }
    }

    return highestVersion.Key;
}
```